# Concatenating a string to execute then running it from another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to execute a concatenated string. I am using the following statement to concatenate the strings to be executed:

```
=(CONCATENATE("=SUM(","'Analytics 2017'!",K4,":",L4, ")"))
```

this works and the cell(c4) holds the concatenated string but when I use

```
=INDIRECT("C4")
```

as an "execute" formula I get an error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do next:

From

```
=(CONCATENATE("=SUM(","'Analytics 2017'!",K4,":",L4, ")"))
```

you need to change to this

```
=(CONCATENATE("'Analytics 2017'!",K4,":",L4))
```

and then from this

```
=INDIRECT("C4")
```

you change to this

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("C4"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am no longer getting an error but the problems is, it's now always giving me a 0 regardless of the numbers i have in the relative cells on the other spreadsheet tab.

Comment: ignore what i said i was referencing a different cell sorry. it works perfectly now! Thanks